# LCA - how to include predictors (conceptual difference between one-step and bias-corrected three-step approach?)

Tags: r, teaching, latent-class

I am trying to teach LCA as part of a modelling course, but I haven't quite made sense of how to deal with testing whether certain (demographic variables) predict class membership.

**Question:** (Why) Should covariates be included in the LCA estimation? It seems wrong to let them influence the identification of classes, but that seems to be happening in the one-step approach.

**Longer explanation:** Say that I am trying to investigate the use of safe-sex strategies based on 10 binary variables (e.g., consistent condom use). An LCA can obviously give me classes of people, which might be associated with demographic predictors (e.g., age). I understand why I should *not* estimate the LCA without covariates and then use multinomial logistic regression based on the predicted classes - that would introduce bias since modal probabilities are turned into supposedly error-free indicator variables. However, the one-step approach as advocated by the `poLCA` package manual, for instance,  also seems problematic. Do I understand correctly that the covariates are then used to model the classes? If the modelled probabilities are already influenced by the covariates, what am I actually testing then when testing whether the covariates are related to the classes? Or is the one-step approach just not appropriate to test whether class membership depends on age, and do I need to find a bias-correction in the three-step approach?

(I have read [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395180/why-covariates-are-used-in-latent-class-analysis-lca) that explains the modelling, but does not directly address this conceptual question.)